# Error 1004 when trying to offset active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to offset the active cell until a certain condition is met. What I've written is

```
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Worksheets("Unit B").Range("D1").Value  
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop
```

Can you please help me correct this ?

---

Giving my entire code for reference:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ddsdata As Range

Dim i As Long
i = 1

Worksheets("Unit B").Select
Set ddsdata = Worksheets("Unit B").Range("E3:E35")
Worksheets("Data Sheet").Select
Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("E1").Select

Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) <> Worksheets("Unit B").Range("D1").Value
i = i + 1

Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ddsdata
```

Comment: how's data laid out in sheet `Data Sheet`? Is it in columns or rows? and what are you trying to do? can you better explain?

Comment: I'm trying to store the data entered in "Unit B" in "Data Sheet". "Unit B" has a form (32 rows) which is filled daily and the data has to be stored date wise in "Data Sheet" without erasing previous data. Data sheet has the same form with all the dates in a month in successive columns.  What I'm trying to do is to look up the date in "Unit B" and match it with that in "Data Sheet" and then paste the data

Comment: any change you could provide a sample screenshot or workbook? it's very hard for me to imagine what you are actually doing and how your data is laid out. Be good if you showed us your `Unit B` and `Data Sheet` before and after copying the matching data.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Avoid using Select / Activate / ActiveCell in your code. Also always refer a cell by sheetname then the cell. eg `Sheet1.Range("A1")` in a workbook for better results.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ddsdata As Range

    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Thisworkoook.Activate
    Set ddsdata = Thisworkoook.Sheets("Unit B").Range("E3:E35")

    Do While Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("E1").Offset(0, i) <> Worksheets("Unit B").Range("D1").Value
            i = i + 1
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ddsdata

End Sub
```